# Present or future in this case

Tags: future-constructions

> I would like to know if the elevator will be working properly when we arrive.

Is it idiomatic ?

Could I write is instead of  will be working don't think so because the trip occurs in the future

Comment: Why do you ask if present tense might be appropriate for something happening in the future?

Comment: Because I ve learned that using if with will is rare. If  it is raining I won't  go outside  but I admit it is not the case here if is not a time clause here

Comment: Yes, fine. Please note: will be working when we arrive. Good. Most learners think it is: when we will arrive. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your first sentence is fine.
It is not idiomatic since every word means exactly what it says and there is no subtle or different meaning that would be understood by a native speaker.
No, you cannot use ""is"" as the tense is wrong, you are asking about the future.

Comment: Surely, you mean is idiomatic....

Comment: The fist sentanc does not use any idioms, but it is **idiomatic** in that it is natural and might well be said by a fluent or native speaker. I often prefer to say it is "natural" to avoid this confusion.

Comment: It seems to depend upon which side of the pond you are. According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/idiomatic) in  American English it is **(of a group of words) having a particular meaning that is different from the meanings of each word considered separately**  but in British English **Idiomatic also means natural in expression, correct without being too formal**. So take your pick.